# Cómo hacer que el Usuario cree el Nombre y Descripción de la Notificación (Alarma)

Tags: java, android

Cómo puedo hacer para que el Usuario cree el Nombre y la descripción de la notificación (Alarma).
Como veréis en mi código (abajo) en el AlarmReceiver creo yo la notificación(Alarma) con el nombre y la descripción, como puedo hacer que esos parámetros se creen mediante los EditText (textonombre y textodescripcion) desde la aplicación?

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    DatePicker datePicker;
    TimePicker timePicker;
    Button btnStart;
    Uri uriAlarm;
    final static int RQS_1 = 1;
    EditText textonombre;
    EditText textodescripcion;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.notif_main);

        datePicker = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datepicker);
        timePicker = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timepicker);
        btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
        uriAlarm = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
        textonombre = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textonombre);
        textodescripcion = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textodescripcion);



        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    setAlarm(uriAlarm);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Alarma ACTIVADA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        });
    }

    private void setAlarm(Uri passuri){

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(datePicker.getYear(),
                datePicker.getMonth(),
                datePicker.getDayOfMonth(),
                timePicker.getCurrentHour(),
                timePicker.getCurrentMinute(),
                00);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), pruebaintento.dos.notif.AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                getBaseContext(),
                RQS_1,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

    }
}
```

AlarmReceiver.java

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent repeating_intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
        repeating_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);


        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,id,repeating_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("NOMBRE")
                .setContentText("DESCRIPCIÓN")
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationManager.notify(id,builder.build());

    }
}
```

Comment: Para poder darte una respuesta más concreta se necesita el código donde tu creas el _Intent_ a que tu _BroadcastReceiver_ va reaccionar.

Comment: @StefanNolde listo, añadido, gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu puedes agregar extras a un intent:

```
intent.putExtra("titulo","Mi Titulo");    
intent.putExtra("texto","Mi Texto");
```

luego armando tu noticia:

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(intent.getStringExtra("titulo"))
            .setContentText(intent.getStringExtra("texto"))
            .setAutoCancel(true);
    notificationManager.notify(id,builder.build());
```

Con la actualisación de tu pregunta con el código de tu Activity te tengo el resto de la solución:

Adjuntemos los extras al *Intent* que pasas al *PendingIntent* para el *AlarmManager* :

```
private void setAlarm(Uri passuri){

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(datePicker.getYear(),
            datePicker.getMonth(),
            datePicker.getDayOfMonth(),
            timePicker.getCurrentHour(),
            timePicker.getCurrentMinute(),
            00);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), pruebaintento.dos.notif.AlarmReceiver.class);
    //los extras
    intent.putExtra("titulo",textonombre.getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra("texto",textodescripcion.getText().toString());
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            getBaseContext(),
            RQS_1,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

}
```

En el receptor se cambia:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent repeating_intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
    repeating_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);


    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,id,repeating_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(intent.getStringExtra("titulo"))
            .setContentText(intent.getStringExtra("texto"))
            .setAutoCancel(true);
    notificationManager.notify(id,builder.build());

}
```

Podrías agregar validación de los datos ingresados para una app de producción, para una tarea alcanza esto.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, pero soy nueva en esto y no comprendo muy bien como debo añadir ahí la ID de mi EditText, me podrías explicar un poco más tu respuesta? Gracias!

Comment: No veo ningun EditText en tu codigo. Si eres tan nuevo, quizas sería una buena idea de empezar de revisar y entender algunos de los ejemplos basicos en Android Studio, la LoginActivity por ejemplo muestra como leer el texto de un EditText. Tambien recommiendo de leer un poco en la documentación oficial sobre [EditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html).

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, pero puse en la pregunta claramente que era para un EditText, sino está en el código es porque no hace falta, en mi opinión, para dar una respuesta valida, gracias.

Comment: Te entendí, sin embargo para conseguir un dato con un EditText vas a necesitar una Activity, con layout y toda la parafernalia. Es mucho más fácil para ti como para los demás si usas AndroidStudio y creas una nueva LoginActivity en vez de que otra persona hace lo mismo y te copia el codigo aquí ;) Trata de ser un poco más concreto con la ayuda ue pides, por favor.

Comment: Añadida mi activity para ver si me puedes ayudar, gracias de nuevo @StefanNolde

Comment: Perfecto, con tu actualización de la respuesta solucionado! Gracias de nuevo @StefanNolde